# Cálculo de relevância de um produto?

Tags: lógica

Vamos dizer que eu tenha os seguintes dados:

```
Video A:
    Procurado: 12000 vezes
    Clicado:   7000 vezes

Video B:
    Procurado: 11000 vezes
    Clicado:   10000 vezes
```

1. Como eu posso calcular qual a relevância destes dois vídeos no meu
   site?
2. Eu devo me basear em outros números além destes? Se sim, quais?

Comment: Esses dados me parecem sem logica para aplicar qualquer padrão de relevância. Se fosse por exemplo, Video B procurado 10000 vezes e clicado 4000 vezes e Video A procurado 7000 vezes e clicado 6000 vezes, acho que seria mais coerente

Comment: Nem sempre a pessoa precisaria procurar por um item para clicar nele, pode ser que ela tenha clicado no item através de um link vindo de outro página, por exemplo uma sugestão na home page

Comment: Pois é, nesse caso a sugestão da home page deveria ser contada como Procurado, para que se possa fazer um cálculo baseado em relevância estatística, para que o numero do Clicado seja sempre um percentual do Procurado

Comment: Alterei os dados, como tal cálculo poderia ser feito?

Comment: Vou fazer os cálculos e postar um exemplo como resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video A Procurado 12000 Clicado 7000 - percentagem A = 58.33% = 0,58

Video B Procurado 11000 Clicado 10000 - percentagem B = 90.9% = 0,90

---

**Cálculo da relevância entre Video B em relação ao video A**

Proporção da amostra agrupada (p) - Combinação das proporções dos dois grupos.

```
      7000 + 10000
p = _________________ = 0,739
      12000 + 11000
```

**Erro padrão** - Medida da diferença entre a sua proporção e a proporção verdadeira. Um número menor significa que a proporção está mais próxima da proporção verdadeira. Já um número maior significa que a proporção está longe da proporção verdadeira

SE = ((0,739*(1-0,739))*(1/12000 + 1/11000))<sup>1/2</sup>

```
  SE= 0,00578
```

Estatística de teste (t) - Uma estatística-t. A quantidade de desvios padrão entre a distância de um número e a média. `t= (percentagem B - percentagem A)/SE`

```
t= (0.9 - 0.58)/0.00578 = 55,36
```

**Relevância estatística** - Se o valor absoluto da estatística de teste é maior que `1,96`* vezes o desvio padrão da média, ele é considerado uma diferença estatisticamente relevante.

*1,96 é o número usado para o nível de confiança de 95%. Veja pagina 10 deste link [**Estatistica Aplicada**](http://www.bessegato.com.br/PUC/iec_transp_09.pdf)

**Conclusão** Como o valor absoluto da estatística de teste `55,36` é muito maior que 1,96, isso significa que a diferença entre Video B e Video A é altamente relevante.